# ng2-pdf-viewer / pdfjs annotation change listener

Tags: pdf.js, pdf-viewer

ng2-pdf-viewer provides a pdfjs `PDFDocumentProxy` on load with some useful properties such as `getFieldObjects()`. These return the annotation layer fields with their initial values.

I however can't find an observable to subscribe onto changes. There are several `eventBus._listeners` objects when I `console.log` the `PDFDocumentProxy` during the `onLoad` function, but I don't think any of these trigger on input change.

Is there a better way to analyze pdf.js annotation fields than to iterate over all field objects and read the html inputs like:

```
 public async onLoad(pdf: PDFDocumentProxy): void {
   const obj = await pdf.getFieldObjects();
   const names: string[] = [];
   Object.keys(obj).forEach((o: string) => names.push(
     ...obj[o].filter(element => element['name'])
       .map(x => x['name'])));

   names.forEach((name: string) => (document.getElementsByName(name)[0] as HTMLInputElement).value;
 }
```